# VBA reference another sheet using indirect

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a novice at VBA...

I am trying to insert an indirect fx using VBA.

I would insert `=INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!"&$A2)` into cell `B2`, cell `B1` contains the other sheet reference, and `A2` contains the cell reference.

How can I acomplish this using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""'""&B$1&""'!""&$A2)"
```

You can put that in a `Sub` and then run it (press f5 whilst the caret/cursor is inside the `Sub`), then enter sheet name in B1, cell reference in A2. Eg...

```
Public Sub TestVBAIndirect()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""'""&B$1&""'!""&$A2)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to do hopefully, it's the most efficient way to accomplish what I want - I'm sure I'll figure that out as I get a bit better at VBA!

Answer (score 2):

you can do `sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Formula = "=Indirect(" & CHAR(34) &  "'" & CHAR(34) & sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value & CHAR(34) &  "'!" & CHAR(34) & sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & ")"` char(34) is the character code for "

Comment: You can 'escape' the double quote by typing two in a row - no need to use CHAR(34). :0) Also, It's `Chr(34)` ... CHAR doesn't exist. And you're referencing the contents of the cells, rather than the address of the cell which isn't what the OP asked for! Sorry to criticise!!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this wasn't 100% what I was after. Appreciate your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
activesheet.cells(2, "B").formula = "=INDIRECT(TEXT(B1, ""'@'!"")&A1)"
```

Comment: How ironic is it that this post just came up in my Low Quality Posts review queue... I'm saying "Looks OK" here.